# Quartz Events Double Cick

Tags: c, macos, quartz-graphics

My question is essentially the same as the one found here:

[Performing a double click using CGEventCreateMouseEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483657/performing-a-double-click-using-cgeventcreatemouseevent)

However, I have tried both of the solutions provided and neither of them works for me. I can perform mouse moves and single clicks but the double click has me stumped.

Any ideas on where I can go from here?

Comment: Are you posting the events from a normal application?  Are you sending them to the same application, or a different one, and in the latter case, is it the front application?

Comment: Right now I'm just running some test code in XCode. When I do a single-click function I can move the pointer to a spot on the project navigator (say at 220x200 where my Products folder is shown) and post a kCGEventLeftMouseDown and then kCGEventLeftMouseUp and it will actually select that folder as if I had done it myself with my mouse. Xcode is the active window and it is maximized in size. It stands to reason that if I follow the code example to set up a double click, it should behave similarly to a double click with a mouse. the pointer moves, but the clicks seem to be not going through

Comment: I think I almost have it now. What I did was set up my demo program to do a single click on one point of the Xcode window, sleep 1 second and then double click on a different place. This time I'm doing it in the editor window so the double click highlights a word of text, just as if I did it with a mouse. Not sure why it would need that, I'm guessing it has something to do with making the window the focus before the double click?